# What is the difference between Nigiyaka and Isogashii

Tags: word-choice

It seems they both mean busy. Can someone tell me what the difference is between them?

Comment: bustling vs busy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are slightly similar but Nigiyaka also has the meaning of lively or "genki". Isogashii feels a little more like a negative way to say busy, while nigiyaka might seem more positive.

For exemple, isogashii would be used for work(negative) while nigiyaka could be used for a party or a parade as meaning crowded/busy(positive)

Another more practical difference would be that isogashii can be used for people, and nigiyaka for events/places. I'm busy(isogashi) / the office is busy(nigiyaka)

Answer (score 3):

- 忙しい is busy.
- 賑やか　ejje.weblio.jp › 英和辞典・和英辞典 › 賑やかの意味・
  そこはとても賑やかです。  It was very lively there. - Weblio Email例文集.
  ( 実に賑やかな男だ  He is a lively fellow―a merry fellow. - 斎藤和英大辞典. ) 
  ( 人の様子が賑やか of a person being cheerful ) - ...

We usually don't think of 　賑やか　as busy.

----- 賑やか　is busy in the sense of (a parade, shopping center, ... (rather than a person) ... being) lively, bustling, full of life and colors, cheers, activity, mirth,  ... .

A busy street (or a busy office) is not  　賑やか　if it's grey and depressing.

- When a person is described as 賑やか　-- it's a description of  his/her personality.
- When a person is described as 忙しい　 --  it's a description of how he/she is at the moment.

A person who seems / appears busy all the time (like personality) "a restless /  fidgety person" is せわしない人 ( 忙しない人 ) or せわしい人【忙しい人】 -- (the former is perh. Kansaiben).