# Can いそがしい mean busy as in 'crowded'

Tags: nuances, adjectives, japanese-to-english

I know 'いそがしい' means busy as in 'having important things to do', but can it also mean busy as in crowded like 'busy street'

Comment: Somewhat related though it may not answer your question.  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39919/what-is-the-difference-between-nigiyaka-and-isogashii/39985#39985

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to say a place is busy, in the meaning of crowded, is 混んでいる, though it is a verb. にぎやか is a similar concept, but is more like "lively" or "happening" than "busy" in the sense that there are many people.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the answer is no. 忙しい only means 'having a lot of things to do'.

[忙しい街](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%BF%99%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E8%A1%97) seems possible, and 忙しい通り may be understood similarly (google search shows it is not common), vaguely as  streets where people are hectic.